# Get row data from dojo store

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have this javascript of code

```
var store;

function dataBind(servletPath){
   store = Observable(Cache(JsonRest({target:servletPath}), Memory()));
}
```

The servletPath will return me a json string that looks like this.

```
[{"colNo":1,"colMemberId":108}]
```

Lets say I call this javascript function and it returns a record to me. How do I get the "colMemberId" from the store?

Comment: did you tried this: store.colMemberId;

Comment: could you add this line alert(store); and post the value of the store variable?

Comment: alert(store) will gives me Object.

Comment: store.colMemberId gives me undefined

Comment: Both store[0] and store[1] gives me undefined also.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont have an idea about the format of the store object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function returns a Dojo store object then you can access it's contents through the use of it's *query()* function like so

```
var store;

function dataBind(servletPath){
    return store = Observable(Cache(Memory({data:[{"colNo":1,"colMemberId":108}]}), Memory()));
}

console.log("store: ", dataBind().query({}));
```

Calling the query function with an empty object as a parameter will return an array containing the entire contents of the store.

Documentation: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Memory.html

Here is a jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/y7ec4byk/4/

Comment: Thank you. To get the specific value, we can use dataBind().query({})[0].colMemberId if the return store value is 1 json object.